# Share article dropdown

Tags: joomla-3.x, articles

I'm looking for a plugin that will allow to have a dropdown social share menu, like the ShutterStock has

[image]

I need next sharing options:

- Facebook
- Instagram
- Copy Link
- Email

probably, few more items will be added in the future. 
Please advice how to get similar functionality.

Comment: Welcome to JSE. While you wait for support, please take the [tour]. Have you conducted any research?  Have you browsed the Joomla Extension Diectory (JED)? Have you trialed any extensions yet?

Comment: Yes, i've had a quick look through some of extensions, most of them has no copy to clipboard option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The free [AddToAny Share Buttons](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/addtoany-share-buttons/) has an option for sharing the link but you might need to customise the styling to your requirements. A plugin and a module are included.

Comment: Great, thx. Missed copy-link option for this extension. Will show this to customer, hope it'll accept :)